# Heroku Failed Deployment ttf Font

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, fonts, build

I've downloaded a font file from online with a .ttf extension. I'm loading it in my css like this

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'ChalkDash';
src: local('ChalkDash'), url(./fonts/ChalkDash.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

It works fine on localhost and the font is loaded properly. My html elements get styled with that font to be clear. However, when I deploy to heroku, I get this error:

```
Counting objects: 30, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (30/30), done.
Writing objects: 100% (30/30), 2.74 KiB | 1.37 MiB/s, done.
Total 30 (delta 23), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> React.js (create-react-app) multi app detected
remote: -----> Configure create-react-app build environment
remote:        Using `NODE_ENV=development`
remote: =====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
remote: =====> Detected Framework: Multipack
remote: =====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
remote: =====> Detected Framework: Node.js
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=development
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 8.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 8.11.1...
remote:        Using default npm version: 5.6.0
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:        added 113 packages in 12.842s
remote: 
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        Clearing previous node cache
remote:        Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (nothing to cache)
remote: 
remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies
remote:        Skipping because NODE_ENV is not 'production'
remote: 
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: =====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-inner-buildpack.git
remote: =====> Detected Framework: React.js (create-react-app)
remote:        Writing `static.json` to support create-react-app
remote:        Enabling runtime environment variables
remote: 
remote: > reverse-hangman-app@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_b679e081d23e4ff1218d9c24620bc77b
remote: > react-scripts build
remote: 
remote: Creating an optimized production build...
remote: Failed to compile.
remote: 
remote: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './fonts/ChalkDash.ttf' in '/tmp/build_b679e081d23e4ff1218d9c24620bc77b/src'
remote: 
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! reverse-hangman-app@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the reverse-hangman-app@0.1.0 build script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-04-24T15_48_50_183Z-debug.log
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile React.js (create-react-app) multi app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to limitless-depths-91672.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/limitless-depths-91672.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/limitless-depths-91672.git'
```

I'm just wondering why this is happening. I've browsed so many posts on this forum but couldn't figure out why it won't work and I have tried a bunch of fixes to no avail. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: filesystem is case sensitive on heroku, have you checked your import uses the same casing as the actually file?
This will still work locally if your file system is not case sensitive such as on macOS

Comment: Yes, the casing is the same as the actual file. I just checked to make sure. @DanHayden

Comment: Could it be because I don't have quotes around the url. Like instead of

url(./fonts/ChalkDash.ttf)

I'd do:

url('./fonts/ChalkDash.ttf')

Comment: It didn't fix it ^